# Weird "assembly not referenced" error when trying to call a valid method overload

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, overloading, entity-framework-6

I'm using method overloading in `Assembly A`:

```cs
public static int GetPersonId(EntityDataContext context, string name)
{
    var id = from ... in context... where ... select ...;
    return id.First(); 
}
    
public static int GetPersonId(SqlConnection connection, string name)
{
    using (var context = new EntityDataContext(connection, false))
    {
            return GetPersonId(context, name);
    }
}
```

When I try to call the second overload from `Assembly B`, VS produces the following compile-time error:

> The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' is defined in an assembly that
> is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
> 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=...'.

`Assembly B` references `Assembly A`. Entity Framework is referenced only in `Assembly A` as `Assembly B` doesn't use it. The call from `Assembly B` looks like this:

```cs
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();                               
    var id = AssemblyA.GetPersonId(connection, name); 
    // compiler error
}
```

What I don't understand is that **the error goes away if I change the method signature** in `Assembly A` to e.g.:

```cs
public static int GetPersonId(SqlConnection connection, string name, bool empty)
```

and change the call to:

```cs
var id = AssemblyA.GetPersonId(connection, name, true); // no error
```

Why is my code not compiling in the first case? It doesn't seem to be related to Entity Framework as the error indicates. I have always thought that C# allows method overloading where method signatures differ only in parameter types. E.g. I can run the following code without problems as expected:

```cs
static void DoStuff(int a, int b) { ... }
static void DoStuff(int a, float b) { ... }
    
DoStuff(10, 5);
DoStuff(10, 5.0f);
```

So why am I getting the error in my situation despite the apparently legal overloads?

Note that from `Assembly B` I have no problems calling other methods that internally use `EntityDataContext`, the only difference is that these methods don't have overloads.

---

**Background**

`EntityDataContext` inherits EF's `DbContext`:

```cs
public partial class EntityDataContext : DbContext
{
    public EntityDataContext() : base("name=EntityDataContext") { }
            
    public EntityDataContext(DbConnection connection, bool contextOwnsConnection) : base(connection, contextOwnsConnection) 
    {
        
    }
}
```

I'm using .NET 4.0 with EF 6 code first to an existing database with some custom ctor overloads added.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C# standard specifies that overload resolution (section 7.5.3) is performed by comparing each matching signature to determine which is a better fit. It doesn't say what happens when a reference is missing, so we must infer that it still needs to compare those unreferenced types.

In your case, the compiler needs a reference to `EntityDataContext` to be able to compare the two overloads. Your call matches the signature exactly so in theory you shouldn't need this, but the standard doesn't specify any such short-circuit behavior.