# Object instantiation fails when using overloaded constructor

Tags: c#, .net

I recently stumbled upon an odd issue which I could not explain and I would be glad if someone could clarify why it happens.

The issue I've encountered is as follows:

I have an interface which is implemented, like so:

```
namespace InterfaceTwo
{
    public interface IA { }
}

namespace InterfaceTwo
{
    public class A : IA { }
}
```

And another interface which is implemented in a different project, like so:

```
namespace InterfaceOne
{
    public interface IB { }
}

namespace InterfaceOne
{
    public class B : IB { }
}
```

I have an object which uses those interfaces in it's constructors, like so:

```
using InterfaceOne;
using InterfaceTwo;

namespace MainObject
{
    public class TheMainObject
    {
        public TheMainObject(IA iaObj) { }

        public TheMainObject(IB iaObj) { }
    }
}
```

And finally, I have a class which aggregates the above object, like so:

```
using InterfaceTwo;
using MainObject;

namespace ReferenceTest
{
    public class ReferenceTest
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            var a = new A();
            var theMainObject = new TheMainObject(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Oddly, this code won't compile with the following error:

> The type 'InterfaceOne.IB' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
>   You must add a reference to assembly 'InterfaceOne, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
>   c:\users\harry.baden\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ReferenceTest\ReferenceTest\ReferenceTest.cs   11  13  ReferenceTest

I also found that if I change one of the overloads to contain an extra parameter - it does compile... What got me thinking that the problem might be related to some sort of reflection issue which the compiler is running.

Thanks,

Barak.

Comment: right click project and make sure the assembly is properly referenced by adding reference to file->rebuild and see what happens

Comment: You need to add a reference in your visual studio solution explorer (under your test  project) to the assemby file created by interfaceOne.
Look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: This isn't an issue of referencing as I don't want ReferenceTest to know about the interface IB or the class B.
I also mentioned that - "I also found that if I change one of the overloads to contain an extra parameter - it does compile...".
I'm assuming that the problem is related to the fact that one of the overloads with the same amount of parameters has IB in it and therefor, while compiling, it needs to know IB as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341651/weird-assembly-not-referenced-error-when-trying-to-call-a-valid-method-overloa) for an explanation of a similar problem that I encountered. To quote the answer from the link:

> The C# standard specifies that overload resolution (section 7.5.3) is performed by comparing each matching signature to determine which is a better fit. It doesn't say what happens when a reference is missing, so we must infer that it still needs to compare those unreferenced types.

In your example, it should be evident what overload you're using, but the compiler is not smart enough and will still try to compare both overloads, which is why both references are required.

Perhaps the easiest - but not the prettiest - solution (if you don't want to include the missing reference - which you may have a good reason not to) is to add an additional dummy parameter, effectively making it obvious to the compiler which overload you're calling; or transforming the two `TheMainObject` constructors into two methods with different names, e.g. `TheMainObjectA(IA iaObj)` and `TheMainObjectB(IB ibObj)` - i.e. avoiding overloading altogether.

Another possible solution is to use the `dynamic` keyword (for .NET 4.0 and above), although some people might discourage this as it can result in runtime errors if you're not careful:

```
public class TheMainObject
{
    public TheMainObject(dynamic obj)
    {
        if (obj is IA)
        {
            // work with IA ...
        }
        else if (obj is IB)
        {
            // work with IB ...
        }
        else
        {
            // exception ...
        }
    }
}
```

This way, the compiler doesn't generate an error since the `obj` parameter is evaluated at runtime - your original code will work. If you choose to use this solution, also consider checking for [RuntimeBinderException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.runtimebinder.runtimebinderexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to avoid accidentally accessing invalid (non-existent) members of the dynamic type.

Comment: Just as I though, thank you very much!
Another fine solution (my friend suggested) is to make a parent interface for both, which will be a bit more enforcing as to the passed type. But, that's only if both types have some common ground and both types are available for editing.
Since, in my case, I didn't want to edit those interfaces, I decided to use "Object" as the parameter type and then safely try to cast it. I guess with your solution as well I'll be going to see what pros and cons would there be to using "dynamic" instead of passing an object.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

namespace dependency issue. The error message pretty mush said it: your TheMainObject depends on InterfaceOne and must be properly referenced

this isn't directly related to constructor overloading...

**Update:** 
It is more of a compiler behavior. To determine which overloaded method to use, the compiler has to

1. check all methods with the same name and same # of parameters to see if all the parameter types are referenced
2. then pick one method that matches the caller's parameter type (explicitly or implicitly).

We can verify step 1 and step 2 are separated with the following code:

```
using InterfaceOne;
using InterfaceTwo;
namespace MainObject
{
    public class TheMainObject
    {
        public TheMainObject(IA obj) { }
        public TheMainObject(IB obj, int x) { }
    }
}

using InterfaceTwo;
using MainObject;
namespace ReferenceTest
{
    public class ReferenceTest
    {
        public static void DoSomething()
        {
            var a = new A();
            var theMainObject = new TheMainObject(a); //no error
        }
    }
}
```

The above code compiles because `TheMainObject(IB obj, int x)` is not a candidate for `new TheMainObject(a)`. However if the constructor is defined as

```
public TheMainObject(IB obj) { }
```

or

```
public TheMainObject(IB obj, int x = 0) { }
```

a reference to InterfaceTwo.IB is required.

You can avoid this kind of reference check by calling the constructor at run-time, but this is **error-prone** and you should be cautious. For example:

```
public static void DoSomething()
{
    var a = new A(); 
    TheMainObject theMainObject = null; 
    var ctor = typeof (TheMainObject).GetConstructor(new[] {typeof (IA)}); 
    if (ctor != null) {
        theMainObject = (TheMainObject) ctor.Invoke(new object[] {a});
    }
}
```

I did a little more research and found the following resources. Basically the type widening/narrowing step needs to know about all the types involved. (The VB version is just for reference because the C# spec is for VS.Net 2003).

[Overload Resolution C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336(v=vs.71).aspx)

[Overload Resolution Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tb18a48w.aspx)

Comment: I have addressed this issue above and I can't seem to copy it to here... Please read my comment to ZivS and Ravingheaven's replies.

Comment: I think it a compiler behavior. when you call TheMainObject(a), the compiler checks all constructors with a single parameter and then find a match by type. Maybe that's why when you update the constructor to TheMainObject(IB iaObj, int x ), the compile error is gone. But if you make second paramter optional : TheMainObject(IB iaObj, int x =0), the error is back again.

Comment: btw, you can use reflection to avoid this reference check at compile time. but you should be cautious if you do so:
var a = new A();
TheMainObject theMainObject = null;
var ctor = typeof (TheMainObject).GetConstructor(new[] {typeof (IA)});
if (ctor != null) theMainObject = (TheMainObject) ctor.Invoke(new object[] {a});

Comment: Yea, the compiler behavior was what I was thinking. Would you like to post it as a comment so I will mark it as the answer?