# Compilers asks for type that is not used in code

Tags: c#

I get a compiler error on a method that has two implementations:

```
namespace Core {
  class DB {
     Run(string s) { }
     Run(NpgsqlCommand n) { }
  }
}

namespace Application {
  class Form {
     void myMethod() {
         DB db = new DB();
         db.Run("");
     }
  }
}
```

`Core` is in a different project, that has Npgql referenced. `Application` is in a project that doesn't have Npgsql referenced. `Application` does have `Core` referenced.

I get the error

> The type 'NpgsqlCommand' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Npgsql, Version=2.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7'.

even though I call `Run(string)`, and am not using `NpgsqlCommand` at all in `Application`. Other functions in `Core.DB` work fine in `Application`.

Why is that?

Comment: Every type used in every possible overload of every member you access must be resolvable. Otherwise the compiler cannot determine whether `Run(NpgsqlCommand)` actually is a better overload for your `Run("")` call. A solution would be to rename `Run(NpgsqlCommand)` to `RunCommand(NpgsqlCommand)`. :)

Comment: See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341651/weird-assembly-not-referenced-error-when-trying-to-call-a-valid-method-overloa): _"The C# standard specifies that overload resolution (section 7.5.3) is performed by comparing each matching signature to determine which is a better fit. It doesn't say what happens when a reference is missing, so we must infer that it still needs to compare those unreferenced types"_. :)

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks. I solved it by making the offending method `private`.